# Python logstash async cannot be used in multiple processes

Tags: python-3.x

excuse me, (sorry , my English is poor)
i have a problem, when i use python logstash async, like:

```
try:
        crawler_logger = logging.getLogger(self.logger_index)
        crawler_logger.setLevel(self.log_host_level)
        crawler_logger.addHandler(AsynchronousLogstashHandler(self.host, self.port, database_path=self.database_path))
        if type(content) == str:
            crawler_logger.info(self.logger_index + ' : ' + content)
        elif type(content) == dict or type(content) == list:
            crawler_logger.info(self.logger_index + ' : ' + json.dumps(content, ensure_ascii=False))
        # crawler_logger.removeHandler(AsynchronousLogstashHandler(self.host, self.port, database_path=self.database_path))
        return True
    except Exception as e:
        return str(e)
```

it can be writed in Log server.but when i use processes,like:

```
def test_processes():

processes = []
for process_num in range(0, 11):
    time.sleep(1)
    process = Process(target=test_process)
    process.start()
    processes.append(process)
for process in processes:
    process.join()
```

it cannot wirte . my Log server is nothing , `test_process()` is the first code block,i want to know why, thank you very much!

Comment: it is really a difficult problem. when i use one process, such as first code block, i excute three times. it wirted 6 data , 1+2+3.

Comment: who can help me....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are on Unix

`AsynchronousLogstashHandler` uses a dedicated thread in order to ship the logs asynchronously.
This makes your main process multithreaded, and in that case the multiprocessing documentation advises not to use the default fork method for creating new processes:

> *fork*
>
> The parent process uses os.fork() to fork the Python interpreter.
> The child process, when it begins, is effectively identical to the
> parent process. All resources of the parent are inherited by the child
> process. Note that safely forking a multithreaded process is
> problematic.
>
> Available on Unix only. The default on Unix.

https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=process#contexts-and-start-methods

Before you create new processes/pools, try:

```
multiprocessing.set_start_method('spawn')
```